# Running Alphabet letters(A,B,C...) in Group footer

Tags: crystal-reports

i want to print Running Alphabet letters(A,B,C...) in Group footer section of crystal report9.0 how can i achieve this... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- my answer assumes that you have another group on {table.name_field} and this is Group 1.
- create a formula, name it 'first_letter', and add the following to its text:

  left({table.name_field},1)
- insert a group on this formula; this will be Group 2.
- move Group 2 above Group 1, essentially swapping their positions
- move the group-name field from the group-header section to the group-footer section